# ForEach not working but For is working fine

Tags: javascript, typescript

My logic works fine with for loop, But It dosen't work with foreach.

Not sure why ?

Below is my code.

```
  for (let i = 1; i < flatItems.length; i++) {
    const flatItem = flatItems[i]
    const depthDiff = flatItem.depth - (stack.length - 1)
    if (depthDiff <= 0) {
      removeFromEnd(stack, -depthDiff + 1)
    }
    const stackTop = stack[stack.length - 1]
    const newEl = {
      text: flatItem.text,
      children: [],
    }
    stackTop.children.push(newEl)
    stack.push(newEl)
  }
```

Output is ,

> root
>   -A
>   -B
>   ---C

And I tried with, `forEach`

```
flatItems.forEach(flatItem => {})
```

But my output differs,

> root
>   -A
>   -A
>   -B
>   ---C

So Issue is an additional `-A`  getting added.

How do I make it working using `forEach`. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

in your for loop- your initial 'i' is set to 1 not from 0. so loop starts from index 1.
In .forEach(), loop starts from 0. hence loop starts from 0.hence you get additional loop and additional 'A'

Answer (score 2):

Your are starting the `for` loop at the index 1 instead zero

```
for (let i = 1; i < flatItems.length; i++)
-------------^
```

`foreach` start at the index zero by default

You can check into your loop if the index is zero and use `return` to get the same result

Like :

```
flatItems.forEach((flatItem, index) => {
    if (index === 0) return;

})
```

Or by using [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) :

```
flatItems.slice(1).forEach(flatItem => {})
```

Comment: So How can i start the forEach at index 1 ?

Comment: That is an X/Y problem. The question is: Why does you array start at 1 instead of 0

Comment: @stacks I posted an update. You can ignore the index zero

Comment: @stacks use array.slice(1).forEach();